# On an existence of a non-arithmetic diffused Borel measure in the real axis $R$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $V$ be a Polish vector space. A Borel measure  $\mu$ in $V$ is
called arithmetic measure if each measurable  set $A$ with
$\mu(A)>0$ has the following property: for an arbitrary $n
>1$ there are $n$ points in $A$ which constitute an arithmetic
progression.

A Borel measure  $\mu$ in $V$ is called diffused if it vanishes on
singletons of $V$, i.e., $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for each $x \in V$.

A linear Lebesgue measure in $R$ is an  arithmetic measure.

Notice that each arithmetic measure in the real axis $R$ is diffused. My question is:
whether the converse is valid ?

or

Does there exist a $\sigma$-finite Borel diffused measure in $R$ which is not arithmetic?

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Please, indicate any reference where can be found the proof of the existence of a perfect set in $R$ whose elements are $Q$-linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the paper by Jan Mychielski where this result was established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a perfect set in R whose elements are Q-linearly independent - See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23202/explicit-big-linearly-independent-sets). Any (diffused) Borel measure supported on such a perfect set is a counterexample.

Notice that such a measure cannot be absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.